# Bucle while con timeOut

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de hacer que mi bucle while haga un console.log() cada segundo.

He probado de varias formas, pero ninguna me ha dado resultado:

Poniendo el setTimeout con cada iteración y después sumar `rep += 1`:

```
    let rep = 1;

    while (rep < 4) {

      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('hola');
      }, 2000)

      //add rep
      rep++;
    }
```

Poner un setInterval por encima del while, y añadir la regla:

```
if(rep==3){
clearInterval(/nombre del intervalo/);
}
```

Hacer el setTimeout al rep++

¿Cómo podría hacerlo correctamente?

¿Sería mejor usar aquí Interval o Timeout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
setInterval(() => {
  console.log("Ejecutar cada 1 seg")
}, 1000);

function cl()
{
  window.clearInterval()
}
```

```html
<button onclick="cl()">CLEAR</button>
```

Con eso ejecutas ese `console.log` cada 1 segundo que va por intervalo

Creo que es eso a lo que te refieres, de no serlo avísame.

Comment: No era eso, pero si que me has dado la solución al problema. El caso era iterarlo 3 veces con un pequeño delay, y estaba emperrado en hacerlo con un bucle cuando no hacía falta realmente. Muchísimas gracias!!!!

Lo que hice fue crear una variable itv, crear otra variable rep = 0; darle el valor itv = setInterval, y dentro del propio intervalo hacer un rep++. Dentro del propio intervalo pondría un if(rep == 4){clearInterval(itv)}

Es una manera que no se me había ocurrido. Eran parecidas, pero con el bucle que me lo fastidiaba. Muchísimas gracias!